# Skipping and connecting sections of controller code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `users/create` controller action that is quite complicated, in part because it is creating one of three types of users, each with their own associated records and set up requirements. Imagine, for example, a form where a `Worker`, a `Company`, and a `Contractor` can be created, and each has its own routing and sends its own e-mail based on a successful vs. failed create.

Despite best intentions, the result is a fair number of the following:

```
if x
  flash[:notice] = abc
  redirect_to :action => "new", :layout => "notice"
elsif y
  flash[:notice] = def
  redirect_to :action => "new", :layout => "notice"
elsif z
  flash[:notice] = ghi
  redirect_to :action => "somethingelse", :layout => "else"
etc.
```

I now have a requirement that changes the repeated `:action => 'new'` to yet another target based on a params value.

Is there a way to reduce this redundancy by saying, in effect, 'Skip to section 2'?

Comment: I didn't understand your question, you were too generic. moving all that logic to helper methods will help. your controllers should stay slim

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a switch/case statement do that?

```
switch(val) {
  case 'x':
  case 'y':
  case 'z':
    // they all perform the same action
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add helper methods where you pass in the user and depending on their role it outputs the appropriate message or route.  This will wind up generating even more code for you, but it could simplify your controller action.  I think it really depends on how you would like to keep it organized.

For example you could have:

```
  helper_method :new_user_message, :new_user_route

  def create
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = new_user_message(@user)
      redirect_to new_user_route(@user)
    end
  end

  def new_user_message(user)
    case user.role
      when x then 'Successful x message'
      when y then 'Successful y message'
      when x then 'Successful z message'
    end
  end

  def new_user_route(user)
    case user.role
      when x then new_x_path
      when y then new_y_path
      when z then new_z_path
    end
  end
```